# Can't set any class/member variables in PHP?

Tags: php, object

```
class posts
{
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->dbase = $db;
        $test = new post(1, $this->dbase);
    }
}

class post
{
    public function __construct($id, &$j)
    {

        $this->ID = $id;
        $this->dbase = $j;

        var_dump($this); // At this point, $this-ID and $this->dbase are both null.
    }
}
```

This is my issue. In the "post" class, I can dump out $j and $id and see that they are both passed perfectly. However, when I try to set $this->ID = $id or $this->dbase = $j, nothing is set. Why would this be?

Comment: typo in the input? You have $i instead of $id. if $j is null then the database is null.

Comment: You can access `$test->ID`, I think.

Comment: Hi Galen, it was a typo when I typed the code here. Yes, I tried dereferencing $j and there is no difference. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
class post
{
    var ID;
    var dbase;
    public function __construct($id, &$j)
    {

        $this->ID = $id;
        $this->dbase = $j;

        var_dump($this); // At this point, $this-ID and $this->dbase are both null.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because post class has no property

Try this

```
class post
{
    private $ID;
    private $dbase
    public function __construct($id, &$j)
    {

        $this->ID = $i;
        $this->dbase = $j;

        var_dump($this); // At this point, $this-ID and $this->dbase are both null.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See
`$test->ID` or `$test->dbase`

```
class posts
{
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->dbase = $db;
        $test = new post(1, $this->dbase);

        echo($test->dbase); // Here you can get all infos
    }
}

class post
{
    public function __construct($id, $j)
    {

        $this->ID = $id;
        $this->dbase = $j;
    }
}

new posts('foo');
```